# SQLite - Datebase colums

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

Can you help solve the problem with the missing column? It seems to me that I did everything right, but I get the error that something is wrong with one column.

ERROR

> **E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: Stezenie** D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.apkadlapacjenta, PID: 11261
>       **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apkadlapacjenta/com.example.apkadlapacjenta.HistoriaPomiarow}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Stezenie
>   (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT Id, Stezenie, Zegar,
>   Data, Posilek, Stres, Samopoczucie, Hiperglikemia FROM Pomiary**
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Stezenie (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT Id,
>   Stezenie, Zegar, Data, Posilek, Stres, Samopoczucie, Hiperglikemia
>   FROM Pomiary
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1443)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:515)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:392)
>           **at com.example.apkadlapacjenta.DbMenager.Query(DbMenager.kt:65)
>           at com.example.apkadlapacjenta.HistoriaPomiarow.LoadQuery(HistoriaPomiarow.kt:55)
>           at com.example.apkadlapacjenta.HistoriaPomiarow.onCreate(HistoriaPomiarow.kt:33)**
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11261 SIG: 9 Disconnected from the
>   target VM, address: 'localhost:8630', transport: 'socket'

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.example.apkadlapacjenta

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.SearchManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.SearchView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_historia_pomiarow.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_historia_pomiarow.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row.view.deleteBtn
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row1.view.*

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class HistoriaPomiarow : AppCompatActivity() {

    var listaWynikow = ArrayList<FIrebaseVal>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_historia_pomiarow)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        //Wczytujemy baze danych
        LoadQuery("%")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        LoadQuery("%")
    }

    private fun LoadQuery(pomiary: String) {
        val dbManager = DbMenager(this)
        val projections = arrayOf(
            "Id",
            "Stezenie",
            "Zegar",
            "Data",
            "Posilek",
            "Stres",
            "Samopoczucie",
            "Hiperglikemia"
        )
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(pomiary)
        val cursor =
            dbManager.Query(projections,null,null,null)
        listaWynikow.clear()
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"))
                val Stezenie = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Stezenie"))
                val Zegar = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Zegar"))
                val Data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Data"))
                val Posilek = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Posilek"))
                val Stres = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Stres"))
                val Samopoczucie = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Samopoczucie"))
                val Hiperglikemia = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Hiperglikemia"))
                listaWynikow.add(
                    FIrebaseVal(
                        ID,
                        Stezenie,
                        Zegar,
                        Data,
                        Posilek,
                        Stres,
                        Samopoczucie,
                        Hiperglikemia ))

            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }

        //Adapter
        val ListaWynikowAdapter = MylistApdater(this, listaWynikow)
        //ustawienia adaptera
        listapomiarow.adapter = ListaWynikowAdapter

        // Wszystkie zadania
        val total = listapomiarow.count
        //actionbar
        val mActionBar = supportActionBar
        if(mActionBar !=null){
            //ustawienia Action Bara
            mActionBar.subtitle = "Masz $total wyników"
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?):Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.notemenu, menu)

        //searchView
        val sv: SearchView = menu!!.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).actionView as SearchView
        val sm = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        sv.setSearchableInfo(sm.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            //implementujemy dwie metody
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                LoadQuery("%$query%")
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                LoadQuery("%$newText%")
                return false
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.dodaj_notatke->{
                startActivity(Intent(this,AddNote::class.java))
            }
            R.id.sortuj->{
                showSortDialog()
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun showSortDialog() {
        //lista opcji
        val sortOption = arrayListOf("Najnowsze","starsze","Tytul rosnaco","Tytul malejaco")
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        mBuilder.setTitle("Sort by")
        mBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sort)

    }




    inner class MylistApdater(
        context: Context,
        private var ListaWynikowAdapter: ArrayList<FIrebaseVal>
    ) : BaseAdapter() {
        var listWynikiArray = ArrayList<FIrebaseVal>()
        var context: Context? = context

        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder","InflateParams")
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            val myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null)
            val Wynik = ListaWynikowAdapter[position]
            myView.stezenienumberpicker.text = Wynik.nodeNumberPicker.toString()
            myView.godzina.text = Wynik.nodezegar
            myView.data.text = Wynik.nodedata
            myView.posilekRG.text = Wynik.nodeposilek
            myView.SP1.text = Wynik.nodehiperglikemia
            myView.SP2.text = Wynik.nodestres
            myView.SP3.text = Wynik.nodesamopoczucie
            //Przycisk kasowania
            myView.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener {
                val dbMenager = DbMenager(this.context!!)
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(Wynik.nodeID.toString())
                dbMenager.delete("ID=?", selectionArgs)
                LoadQuery("%")
            }
            return myView
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return ListaWynikowAdapter[position]
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()

        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return ListaWynikowAdapter.size

        }

    }
    private fun GoToUpdateFun(Wyniki: FIrebaseVal) {
        val intent = Intent(this,AddPomiary::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Id",Wyniki.nodeID)//wpisz Id
        intent.putExtra("Stezenie",Wyniki.nodeNumberPicker)
        intent.putExtra("Zegar",Wyniki.nodezegar)
        intent.putExtra("Data",Wyniki.nodedata)
        intent.putExtra("Posilek",Wyniki.nodeposilek)
        intent.putExtra("Hiperglikemia",Wyniki.nodehiperglikemia)
        intent.putExtra("Stres",Wyniki.nodestres)
        intent.putExtra("Samopoczucie",Wyniki.nodesamopoczucie)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

DBMENAGER

```
package com.example.apkadlapacjenta

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder
import android.widget.RadioGroup
import android.widget.Toast

class DatebaseMenagerPomiary(context: Context) {

    //Database name
    var dbName = "Historia Pomiarów"
    //table name
    var dbTable = "Wyniki"
    //kolumny
    var colID = "Id"
    var colStezenie = "Stezenie"
    var colZegar = "Zegar"
    var colData = "Data"
    var colPosilek = "Posilek"
    var colStres = "Stres"
    var colSamopoczucie = "Samopoczucie"
    var colHiperglikemia = "Hiperglikemia"

    //wersja
    var dbVersion = 1

    //Tworzymy tabele
    val sqlCreateTable =
        "CREATE TABLE$dbTable($colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colStezenie TEXT, $colZegar TEXT, $colData TEXT, $colPosilek TEXT, $colStres TEXT,$colSamopoczucie TEXT, $colHiperglikemia TEXT)"

    var sqlDB: SQLiteDatabase? = null

    init {
        val db = DatabaseHelperWyniki(context)
        sqlDB = db.writableDatabase
    }


     inner class DatabaseHelperWyniki : SQLiteOpenHelper {
        var context: Context? = null
         constructor(context: Context) : super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion) {
            this.context = context
        }

        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
            db!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
            Toast.makeText(this.context,"baza danych utworzona...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
            db!!.execSQL("zamknij tabele jeśli nie istnieje" + dbTable)
        }


    }

    fun  insert(values:ContentValues):Long{
        val ID  = sqlDB!!.insert(dbTable,"",values)
        return ID
    }
    fun Query(projection:Array<String>,selection:String,selectionArgs:Array<String>,sorOrder:String): Cursor {

        val qb = SQLiteQueryBuilder()
        qb.tables=dbTable
        val cursor = qb.query(sqlDB,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sorOrder)
        return cursor
    }

    fun delete(selection: String,selectionArgs: Array<String>):Int{
        val count = sqlDB!!.delete(dbTable,selection,selectionArgs)
        return count
    }

    fun update(values:ContentValues,selection: String,selectionArgs: Array<String>): Int {
        val count = sqlDB!!.update(dbTable,values,selection,selectionArgs)
        return count
    }



}
```

NODE CLASS dont see on name :D

```
package com.example.apkadlapacjenta



class FIrebaseVal(
    nodeID: Int, nodeNumberPicker:String,
    nodezegar:String,
    nodedata:String,
    nodeposilek: String,
    nodehiperglikemia: String,
    nodestres: String,
    nodesamopoczucie: String
    ) {
    var nodeID: Int?= nodeID
    var nodeNumberPicker: String? = nodeNumberPicker
    var nodezegar:String?=nodezegar
    var nodedata:String?=nodedata
    var nodeposilek: String? =nodeposilek
    var nodehiperglikemia:String?=nodehiperglikemia
    var nodestres:String?=nodestres
    var nodesamopoczucie:String?=nodesamopoczucie
}
```

Mates can you explain me what is wrong ? Thx

Comment: If you made changes to the table like adding or renaming columns after you first ran the app, then uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Comment: i made this, and dont work ;///

Comment: Try in a clean device/emulator.

Comment: Unfortunately, cleansing does nothing ;/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you add this column but forget to add migration from old database version. You can check it by clear all application data (or delete and install it). If reinstall fix the problem you should create migration from old database verstion to new

Also you can refactor all your database to use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) instead of ugly ORMLite.
It's friendly and powerfull persistance library from google

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue may be due to the line :-

```
val sqlCreateTable =
    "CREATE TABLE$dbTable($colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colStezenie TEXT, $colZegar TEXT, $colData TEXT, $colPosilek TEXT, $colStres TEXT,$colSamopoczucie TEXT, $colHiperglikemia TEXT)"
```

There is no space between the **TABLE** keyword and the table name.

Try changing to :-

```
val sqlCreateTable =
        "CREATE TABLE $dbTable($colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colStezenie TEXT, $colZegar TEXT, $colData TEXT, $colPosilek TEXT, $colStres TEXT,$colSamopoczucie TEXT, $colHiperglikemia TEXT)"
```

And then after uninstalling the App or deleting the App's data try rerunning.